# Django-star-ratings model and queryset sorting

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset, rating-system

I am new to Django and I was hoping to get a little help with integrating the `django-star-ratings` package.
As per the documentation I have the model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    ratings = GenericRelation(Rating, related_query_name='foos')
```

and I'm not entirely sure how is sorting the queryset works so I plugged

```
url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.filter(ratings__isnull=False).order_by('ratings__average'),
                                template_name="UploadApp/upload.html")),
```

as a listview into my urls.py  to pass the view . My first question is: even after making migrations, the new ratings field is not showing up in my admin. Any ideas on where I've gone wrong?
Second question: have I done the listview sorting bit right?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you register it in `admin.py`?

Comment: Ok, so I just realized that it does show up in admin, however it looks like it's a separate object called STAR_RATINGS. Not sure why it would be seperate from the Post model I created, or how to connect the two

Comment: Also I did register Post in admin